# "input cannot be resolved" using methods

Tags: java

```
package methods;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayBox {

public static double FindDimensions (int length, int width) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in); 
    int box ; 

    System.out.println ("Please enter the length of the box"); 
    length = input.nextInt();//input cannot be resolved 
    System.out.println (" Please enter the width of the box");
    width = input.nextInt(); //input cannot be resolved 


    return box  ; 
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
}
```

I don't understand why it keeps saying input cannot be resolved. I know this is a very basic question but I need your help.

Comment: Your Scanner instance is called `scanner` not `input`

Comment: oh thanks it works !